# How do I programmatically verify a certificate chain using OCSP?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, client-certificates, pki, ocsp

Suppose I receive a chain of certificates: `[leaf cert, intermediate cert 1, intermediate cert 2, intermediate cert 3...]` How do I manually verify that the certificate has not been revoked using OCSP requests? The leaf certificate has OCSP server attached to it.

I have listed the possible options that I have thought of:

1. issue OCSP request with the `CreateOCSPRequest(intermediate cert, leaf cert)` for each intermediate cert in the cert chain (ie. `CreateOCSPRequest(intermediate cert 3, leaf cert)`, `CreateOCSPRequest(intermediate cert 2, leaf cert)`, `CreateOCSPRequest(intermediate cert 1, leaf cert)`, etc.)
2. just one OCSP request with `CreateOCSPRequest(intermediate cert 1, leaf cert)`, not checking the other certs in the chain
3. issue OCSP request with the `CreateOCSPRequest(intermediate cert, leaf cert)` for each intermediate cert in the cert chain, except the last cert in the cert chain (which appears to be the approach here: https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/-/blob/pkg/security/ocsp.go?L48)
4. issue OCSP request with the `CreateOCSPRequest(intermediate cert, leaf cert)` for each intermediate cert in the cert chain, until we reach a root cert that we can trust
5. issue OCSP request with `CreateOCSPRequest(cert's issuer cert, cert)` for each intermediate cert in the cert chain (have the intermediate cert as the cert to check in the OSCP request, instead of the leaf cert, so we issue requests `CreateOCSPRequest(intermediate cert 1, leaf cert)`,`CreateOCSPRequest(intermediate cert 2, intermediate cert 1)`,
   `CreateOCSPRequest(intermediate cert 3, intermediate cert 2)`, etc.)
6. something else

My current implementation is option 1. I don't think my solution (option 1) is the right answer, however, as I get an `unauthorized` error when I try to issue an OCSP request with (intermediate cert 4, leaf cert) in my test cert chain.

`CreateOCSPRequest(issuer, cert)` is the placeholder function that creates an OCSP request with the issuer and cert. I'm using the `ocsp.CreateRequest` in Golang, although I'm sure there are similar functions in other languages.

Comment: *"CreateOCSPRequest(issuer, cert) is the placeholder function that creates an OCSP request with the issuer and cert. "* - which implicitly says that your option 1 is wrong since there is only on issuer of the leaf cert. All other intermediates are not issuers of the leaf cert. And just from your ording I don't understand the difference between option 1, 3, 4

Comment: In general - if you want to check the OCSP status of a certificate you have to use CreateOCSPRequest with this certificate and its direct issuer certificate (there is only one) and send it to the OCSP URL given in the certificate to check. If you want to check for the leaf cert do it for the leaf cert. If you want to check it for all intermediates too, then do this also for all intermediates - each of these also has a OCSP URL (which might be different from the one in the leaf cert) and an issuer certificate (only one).